# first program of OpenGL using c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning opengl using c++.I am using ubuntu and used i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -o output1 openWindow.cpp to build the file it is building without error but when executable file opened it is giving error : An error occurred while loading the archive. Can anyone help me to start with openGL using cpp.

Comment: We need details. This is not a sufficiently specific question.

Comment: Actually i am new to use opengl. I dont know exactly how to install and build opengl program but i have tried sample open window program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a cross-compiler for Windows, and you are trying to run the binary on Linux (I assume *ubantu* is a linux distribution).

Just use normal `g++` from `apt-get install g++`.

---

[Here's a GLFW usage example](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html), if you'd like to see some code. GLFW is cross-OS, so it will still work when compiled on windows (by *appropriate* compiler, obviously). It also has [build instructions](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html).

Comment: But then it is giving error for windows.h file. fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
yes my ubantu is 12.04 LTS.

Comment: @Nish `<windows.h>` is a Windows-specific file. To compile the code on Linux, you need Linux-compatible windows handling, such as GLFW.

Comment: can you please give any reference to start with opengl using c++ from basics.

Comment: @Nish I've edited it into answer.

Comment: is it not possible to build opengl programs without using any external lib.

Comment: @Nish You'd need at least X Window libraries anyway, and of course your driver's `opengl.lib`. OpenGL is not a part of C++, it's an external thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45383/discussion-between-nish-and-bartek-banachewicz)